# Find the latest value in a row then enter the date in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If you look at the image below we are trying to get a formula working, so we can do the following.

In Row 6 we need to locate the last Full in the column that is the date before the current date.

So for Blandc01 we have a full in Row 6 and column UJ6. WE need to find the latest Full in that column and then put the date at the top of that column in the cell that says Last Full in this case it's B12.

If for example you look at Blanbck01, we have our last full on 04/07/2014 in column UF, so the cell B8 has that date in it from Cell UF6.

So how do we use a series of functions to determine the last Full in the respective row, find that date of the column and put this in the relevant cell on the left.

I have updated the image to include the row numbers.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @punts I have now updated the image to include the Row Numbers. Sorry for the emission of them in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to pnuts comments, it is apparent that a lookup using just "full" won't work on an unsorted list.  So here is one that will

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(C5:XD5="full"),$C$3:$XD$3),"")
```

You will need to change the row references to properly reflect the two vectors.  The first array is the row where you are looking for "full", the second is where the dates are located.

The OP has been asking more questions in the comments section.  It seems he wants to return the latest dates where either "full" or "syn.full" is seen in the particular line.

If merely looking for the substring "full" will be sufficient (in other words, if there are no other strings that contain "full" that need to be excluded, then one can use:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER(SEARCH("full",C6:XD6)),$C$3:$XD$3),"")
```

On the other hand, if there might be other strings containing "full" which we want to ignore (e.g. fullness), and if the dates in row 3 are in ascending order, then try the following:

```
=MAX(IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(C6:Z6="full"),$C$3:$Z$3),0),IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(C6:Z6="syn.full"),$C$3:$Z$3),0))
```

If you use the latter, you should format the cell to not show 0's (eg:  yyyy-mm-dd;;  ) or wrap the whole formula in an IF to return the null string if the result is zero.

Comment: @pnuts By "and ponder" I meant only to think more about the behavior of LOOKUP with unsorted text. The other formula works because LOOKUP seems to ignore error values, so it sees only the '1's, seeing a sorted array, matching the last.  BTW have you been deleting your comments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...Is it possible to check if it's a Full or Syn. Full ?

Comment: @HenryEdwards The answer is yes.  However, your comment here can be interpreted several ways.  Provide clarification in your original post, and mark that clarification as such.

Comment: Hi, thanks - So at the moment it fills in a Full. if C5:XD5="full". But this can be either a Full or Syn. Full 

It's about backups, so on that day it could be either a Full or Syn. Full It varies on the day...so it would be useful to distinguish between them both,

Comment: @HenryEdwards I don't see any clarification of precisely what you want in any edit to your **original post** (your **original question**). Did you try anything? What happened? How did it differ from what you expected.  It should be obvious that to find the last syn. full (or any other phrase), you just have to substitute that phrase in the formula.

Comment: So I want it to check if there is a Full or Syn. Full in that Row. So in Row 6 if the latest one is a Syn. Full then put the date in cell B8 or if it's Full then put the date in.

I have tried this, but only picks up the first one and does not check the OR...=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(C6:XD6="Full")*OR(C6:XD6="Syn. Full"),$C$3:$XD$3),"")

Comment: @HenryEdwards You still are not putting your new request into your original question.  Are you not able to edit that question?  In any event, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Finding the last match is always more difficult than the first one but I think I have something that works.  This is an array function so has to be entered with **ctrl+shift+enter**

```
=indirect("R3C" & max((UB6:UJ6="full")*column(UB6:UJ6)),FALSE)
```

A break down of the function is as follows

(UB6:UJ6="full") returns an array of 1s and 0s (1 where it evaluates true).  This is then multiplied by the column number (given in numbers, not letters).  Once these are multiplied together we have a list of all the columns that have the word "full"

The indirect function allows you to use R1C1 style formulas if the second variable is False so the column can be inputted directly as a number.  The R3 at the beginning means the value returned with be in row 3.